# c# Get last or final x days in a month

Tags: c#

How do I get last x days in a month? I wanted to see if today's date will fall with in range of last x days in a month.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,
                                DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year,today.Month));

for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(lastDay.AddDays(-i));
}
```

I want to get list of final x days in a month and compare with day's date and see if today's date falls with in those x days. Hope it make sense now.

Comment: You could just add `x` to todays date, and see if that is still in the same month...

Comment: So what's the problem with code you've shown except it is not the most optimized one?

Comment: I want to get a list of final x days and compare with todays date to see if it falls in that range.

Comment: Change your for loop to `for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lastDay.AddDays(-i));
            }`

Comment: Well @ChrisF i don't see this as a exact duplicate. He already knows how to get the last day of the month, he is doing it in his code...

Comment: you don't need to do a loop.  A simple if statement can do the same   if (today >= lastDay.AddDays(-4) && today <= lastDay)